# Treasure Island

Tags: treasure-hunt

The treasure is somewhere on this map:

[image: treasure island]

Blue is water; green is grass; yellow is sand; gray is rock.

Your clue is N6E4S2W1, and your adventure starts on the central dark green square.

Answer (score 9):

The treasure could be in any of these spaces.

> [image: Map]
>  N6E4S2W1 are compass directions, but we don't know which way the map is oriented.

Comment: The nazis strike back xD

Comment: Notice that all paths end on rocks. Could that be a clue to a twist with the directions?

Comment: One side of the map is darker, it can be linked to the sun position. So if we know the time and the island position we can guess orientation.

Comment: only one of these is a strictly land path (not explicitly required), and why only orthogonal rotations?

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt None of the lines represent routes, they just represent working out where the treasure is. I don't see why you would have to go any particular route to get there. Since the treasure must be in a rock space then I assume that rock spaces at least are accessible. If we consider north as a diagonal direction then you end up moving like a bishop and rule out half the squares. That doesn't break the puzzle but it's just a bit wierd so I assume it's not intended.

Comment: Notice that 3 of those 4 paths have water in their way. If we assume we cant swim, then only the Up path works.

Comment: Assuming the hint uses leetspeak and using an anagram solver gives `we6 n421s`.

Comment: Maybe this actually means the treasure is in Berlin...

Answer (score 6):

Treasures are in here:

> Under ROCK square. 
>  [image]

Because:

> "N6E4S2W1" means : 6 up, 4 right, 2 down and 1 left

Comment: But surely that's only what they WANT you to think? If it was just a matter of following the explicit instructions, it wouldn't be much of a puzzle.

Comment: Agree. As @Richard has answered - we do not know the orientation of map.

Answer (score 2):

The treasure is :

> the grey box top right, position 12 / 4 (11 on the right from top left, then 3 under)

More explanations :

> 6 steps north, 4 east, 2 south, 1 west

Pro skills :

> [image]

Comment: Won't you end up in (11,4) if you do that?

Comment: I'm quite bad at numbers :3 trying to explain it